# Share project between Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 community and created C++ project.
I want to share the project with a colleague working with Visual Studio 2012 professional.

Once he took the project he had to change the toolset to v110 and it worked just fine for him.

When he shared it back with me I got the message:

```
error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2012 (Platform Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found.
To build using the v110 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 build tools.
Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade Solution...".
```

I do not want to upgrade the solution, as that will cause us each time to change the project, but I couldn't find anywhere to download the VS2012 build tools.

Where can I find Visual Studio 2012 build tools?

Comment: You can get an ISO for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop here:  http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9816768  I have no idea if this will do what you need.  You might want to suggest that your colleague install VS 2013 Community edition.

Comment: I am not sure what to do with the ISO. Switching to community edition is not an option, because he has the professional version and will not switch to community one.

Comment: @IgalS. I think there is a web installer too if you prefer http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34673

Comment: Community and Professional are the same thing.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx  He can have both installed at the same time so he doesn't lose anything.  You could also use CMake or something similar to generate solutions for each of you from a set of config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 installed on the same machine. Once you have both installed you can use the Visual Studio 2012 compiler in Visual Studio 2013.

So I suggest you install Visual Studio 2012. I think [Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34673) should be enough.

Alternatively, your colleague can install Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition alongside his existing Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition. I think the features are roughly equivalent the only question is if they are breaking the [license terms](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/dn877550).

Comment: For some reason I got to the download page, but it doesn't do anything. Possibly Microsoft problem. I will try again later.

Comment: Managed to download, install and compile the project within the VS2013 IDE.